# TWIG - How to override block inside Embed, but in child template?

Tags: symfony, twig

So, I have 3 templates: 1. Embed Widget with some params, 2. Global layout for every pages, 3. Single page.

I want to make block in Layout which would be overrided by Page, but when I want to put this block inside Embed widget, then it does not work.

`file: Widget/awesome.html.twig` (Embed widget)

```
<div id="{{id|default('awesomeWidget')}}">
    {% block widget_body %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

`file: Layout/layout.html.twig`

```
{% block layout_body %}
    {% embed 'AcmeFoobarBundle:Widget:awesome.html.twig' with 
            {'id':'myAwesomeWidget'} only %}
        {% block widget_body %}
            {% block I_WANT_TO_OVERRIDE_THIS %}
            {% endblock %}
        {% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}
{% endblock %}
```

`file: Portal/page.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'AcmeFoobarBundle:Layout:layout.html.twig' %}

{% block I_WANT_TO_OVERRIDE_THIS %}
    Hello World
{% endblock %}
```

Is this possible to do this idea somehow?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't do like this. Embed works like include and extends, so that block I_WANT_TO_OVERRIDE_THIS is actually in your 'extended 'awesome.html.twig'. Page is extending layout.html.twig not the awesome, so there is no I_WANT_TO_OVERRIDE_THIS block for page.html

You should consider changing this to have a placeholder for your widget and embed them on page.html.twig level.

If you really need this way, you can eventually do it like this:
In layout.html.twig:

```
{% set overrideWidgetPart %}
   {% block I_WANT_TO_OVERRIDE_THIS %}{% endblock %}
{% endset %}

{% block layout_body %}
    {% embed 'AcmeFoobarBundle:Widget:awesome.html.twig' with 
            {'id':'myAwesomeWidget', overrideWidgetPart: overrideWidgetPart } only %}
        {% block widget_body %}
            {{ overrideWidgetPart  }}
        {% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is this "overrideWidgetPart: overrideWidgetPart" really ned?  I applied this to a similar problem and removed that part, and it works. Thanks :)

Comment: @Diguin there is no need for them in this snippet in terms of a final result but the idea is to restrict undesired variables to appear in your template. Consider you have bunch of different variables outside. You would rather prevent them from reaching your template to avoid names collisions and to simplify debugging. Using `with { ... } only` is always a good practice.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer helped me figure out a similar case where I'm using an embed inside of an embed and I wanted to be able to inject html in the child embed block.

If you look in users.html you'll see I use `{% set footer %}{% endset %}` which allows me to pass the html into the child embed `{% block footer %}` block.

users.html

```
{% embed 'user_widget.twig'
    with { user: user } only %}        
    {% set footer %}
        <div class='footer'>content here</div>
    {% endset %}
{% endembed %}
```

user_widget.twig

```
{% embed 'user_widget.tpl' with {
    open: true,
    id: user.uid
}%}
    <div class='user_header'>{{ user.name }}</div>    
    {% block content %}
        {% embed "user_info.twig" with {
            id: user.id,
            photo: user.picture,
            footer_html: footer} only %}
                {% block footer %}{{ footer_html }}{% endblock %}
        {% endembed %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

user_info.twig

```
<div class='user_info' id='{{ id }}'>
    <img class='user_photo' src='{{ photo }}'>    
    {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: does this work even if you want to access the the child scope from the parent-parent? let's say  in users.html you want to do `content here for {{ id }}` where `id` is that available in `user_info.twig`

Comment: acutally of course, because the user is defined in the parent-parent scope. Actually what I was curious about was in the situation where the block in the last child that you want override is situated within a for loop where other data not directly accessible from the parent-parent would be normally available.